# VSCode GitLens Extention stashes show untracked files

Tags: vscode-extensions, git-stash, gitlens

When looking at GitLens stashes, it shows a bunch of untracked files that looks as if they were included in the stash. However, only one file was actually stashed which is what shows when I run `git stash show`.

Why is GitLens tracking all of these files and how do I get it to only show what was actually stashed?

It's really hard to determine what was in the stash because of all the clutter.

[Git Lens Stash](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1GZLh.png)

[Actual Stash Listing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kstI1.png)

Comment: To provide product feedback, you should use GitHub, https://github.com/eamodio/vscode-gitlens/issues